# How to create a view of different number of columns for every row using RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-view

I want to create a UI in my android app, where at starting a `RecyclerView` having 2 `columns` consisting of `CardViews` in every `row`.

Upon tapping a row in column1 and after that upon tapping a row in column2, the row in column 2 should move against `row` in column1. After the row has moved, instead of 2 card views, I want a single card view. Is that possible at run time ?

I have explored the `RecyclerView` with `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` too, but I couldn't find a solution where on run time, 2 columns can be destroyed and a single column consisting of a `CardView` can be created.

If anyone can guide me or can help me in creating such UI where in `recyclerview`, actions on single item can acknowledged properly and on run time number of `columns` can be changed based on such actions, it will be great.

Comment: You want two columns that merge when clicked?

Comment: Yes Stefan, But i don't think StaggerdGridLayoutManager can help me in this.

Comment: Have you tried writing some custom animations to merge the two?

Comment: No, I haven't tried custom animations. How will custom aninations will help into this ?

Comment: You can make it look like the two are merging, when actually there is a third one  (the combined one) getting shown more during animation. Until completion, when only the third one is shown. Possibly not the nicest solution.

Comment: Yes, it is a possible solution but i need to update other rows of column 2 based on the match. Like if first row's first column matched with 4th row's 2nd column then in first row's second column there should be data of 4th row's second column and all other rows of second column should update based on that case. So it should behave like Independent cards having a GridView which can merge on some condition. Do you suggest that i should go ahead with StaggeredGridLayoutManager for giving a look like GridView ?